# Angular 6 routing redirecting

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm new to `Angular` and writing my first `Angular` application for admin dashboard.

I have to setup two layouts

1. for authentication like login, logout, forgot-password, etc
2. admin dashboard will come after login

for that I have setup two layout components

1. admin-layout
2. auth-layout

and put all auth components in auth module

The directory structure of my application is like

```
app
|- e2e
|- node_modules
|- src
   |- app
      |- auth (module)
         |- login (component)
            |- login.component.ts
            |- login.component.html
         |- register (component)
            |- register.component.ts
            |- register.component.html
         |- auth.module.ts
      |- dashboard (component for auth users)
         |- dashboard.component.ts
         |- dashboard.component.html
      |- layouts ( directory)
         |- admin-layout (component)
            |- admin-layout.component.html
            |- admin-layout.component.ts
            |- admin-layout.module.ts
            |- admin-layout.routing.ts
         |- auth-layout (component)
            |- auth-layout.component.html
            |- auth-layout.component.ts
            |- auth-layout.module.ts
            |- auth-layout.routing.ts
      |- app.component.html
      |- app.component.ts
      |- app.module.ts
      |- app-routing.module.ts
   |- assets
   |- index.html
```

content of **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ComponentsModule} from './components/components.module';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    AuthLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

content of **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {AdminLayoutComponent} from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AuthLayoutComponent} from './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: AdminLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'}
    ] },
  { path: '', component: AuthLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.module#AuthLayoutModule'}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

content of **admin-layout.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

content of **admin-layout.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AdminLayoutRoutes } from './admin-layout.routing';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../icons/icons.component';
import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    IconsComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminLayoutModule { }
```

content of **auth-layout.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthLayoutRoutes} from './auth-layout.routing';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {AuthModule} from '../../auth/auth.module';
import {LoginComponent} from '../../auth/login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../../auth/register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AuthLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthLayoutModule { }
```

content of **auth-layout.routing.ts**

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from '../../auth/login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../../auth/register/register.component';
import {ForgotPasswordComponent} from '../../auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import {ResetPasswordComponent} from '../../auth/reset-password/reset-password.component';

export const AuthLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent}
];
```

> Question

On accessing `localhost:4200` is redirecting to `localhost:4200/dashboard` and it's working as `dashboard` path is set in admin routing.

But on accessing `localhost:4200/login` is redirecting to `localhost:4200` and login routing is not working from auth routing.

> App code url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwevqj
>   App url: https://angular-lwevqj.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your routes should be like -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'}
    ] },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.module#AuthLayoutModule'}
    ]}
];
```

Also your auth routes should be like -

```
export const AuthLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent}
];
```

Calls should be -

Login - `localhost:4200/auth/login`
Register - `localhost:4200/auth/register`
Similarly others

Comment: can't I have routing to `login` or `regiter` without any prefix? means directly at `/login` and `/register` instead of `/login/register`?

Comment: Actually you have to distinguish your routes in your app module routes else it will always go to the first matching

Comment: I would suggest to have like `/auth/login`  and `/auth/register`  that would be better.

Comment: I understand but since first two paths are same initially listening at `` then why not it will work for third one. Also, even if it does not work, why redirecting? there is no redirecting path in `admin route`.

Comment: { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }, this was looking for full  match of path so it was going to second if you anything like . localhost:4200/abc. You can try shuffling admin and auth , auth will work but again admin shouldn't.

Comment: as per your suggestion, I suffeled position of auth and admin routes and yes it's not working and all requests are redirecting to `/`, even `/login` and `/dashboard` are now redirecting to `/`. I tried by removing first path which redirects to `/dashboard` even they are redirecting to `/`

Comment: earlier I had a path `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}` which I removed later today. Is it causing such redirection?

Comment: `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}`  this `wildcard` if no other path match it will be the default one. Note: wildcard should be kept in last otherwise everything redirects to `dashboard`. Hope this make clear bit.

Comment: I tried giving prefix names `admin` and `auth` to both urls, but admin is working and `auth` is still redirecting to `/`

Comment: Update your current routes details in question or share your code on `stackblitz`. It difficult to say whats going missed as if `admin` is working `auth` should work as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176309/discussion-between-edupeeth-and-anuj-tbe).

Answer (score 2):

You should change your main routes (replace '' with 'login'), I think the problem is here:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: AdminLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'}
    ] },
  { path: 'login', component: AuthLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.module#AuthLayoutModule'}
    ]}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using this code **{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }** in
***(app-routing.module.ts)*** file so on accessing **localhost:4200** is redirecting to **localhost:4200/dashboard** and it's working as dashboard.

firstly set your *by default* path location where you want to redirect like **{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }**
 if you will use this code then your url automatic redirect to login component when you will enter ***localhost:4200***.

Comment: I understand but why redirecting to `/` on visiting `/login`? there is no redirect path defined except `/dashboard`. So even if it redirect, it should be redirecting to `/dashboard`

Comment: so can you tell me that where is redirect route by default ?

Comment: and also tell me where do you want to navigate your route(path)?

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting to `/dashboard` as your  global routing file has defined on the top to redirect any calls to Dashboard component.

**See the first `path` definition in your global routing file**

In this angular project the hierarchy is built up. It has been assumed that the user will go to dashboard first.

If you want to go directly to Login Component just add `/login`  for the login component route in your global routing file.

But please take care of routing in your login module. I would suggest to use child routing of the form `/child1/child2` only if you really want to have that dependent url.

If you want to make some of your components to be of the form `/name` , they should be present globally.

You can see more on [Angular 6 Docs](http://angular.io)